# Unable to deploy my react native app to app store (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, crash, crash-log

I'm trying to deploy my app to the apple app store, the app was created in react native, I sent my app to be reviewed with apple, it was rejected, their response was:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completenes.
>
> We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will launch without crashing.
>
> Resources
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please review Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports.

The thing is that I have tested my app with several devices and several versions of iOS and I don't have this problem, not even a similar one. Please, I would like to know what could be the problem and how to solve it if possible, thanks in advance. The crash log is:

```
{"app_name":"FerretotalApp","timestamp":"2017-09-05 12:32:18.36 -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"840b485c-24ee-3009-8505-3f2079d392c9","adam_id":1277268357,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.mood.ferretotalapp","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)","incident_id":"A79E6031-7C90-4230-ACEA-F0BBC9584F4F","name":"FerretotalApp"}
Incident Identifier: A79E6031-7C90-4230-ACEA-F0BBC9584F4F
CrashReporter Key:   4dbc273d8c0889e8d3edc6b9ac6d3dca128497c3
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             FerretotalApp [29254]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4235FE89-BB4B-4025-8EBF-F74C27F0A94F/FerretotalApp.app/FerretotalApp
Identifier:          com.mood.ferretotalapp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mood.ferretotalapp [5079]


Date/Time:           2017-09-05 12:32:18.2659 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-09-05 12:32:13.4355 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1886bafe0 0x18711c538 0x1886baf28 0x100103218 0x100126cbc 0x100126524 0x1875729e0 0x1875729a0 0x187580ad4 0x1875762cc 0x187580fa8 0x187582a50 0x1875827d0 0x18777b100 0x18777acac)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018713015c 0x187114000 + 115036
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018859745c 0x18858e000 + 37980
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001885a1cf0 0x18858e000 + 81136
3   FerretotalApp                   0x00000001000f4b88 0x1000e8000 + 52104
4   FerretotalApp                   0x00000001000f93b8 0x1000e8000 + 70584
5   FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100108bd4 0x1000e8000 + 134100
6   FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100154e6c 0x1000e8000 + 446060
7   FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100157280 0x1000e8000 + 455296
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018859ec90 0x18858e000 + 68752
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018859eb5c 0x18858e000 + 68444
10  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010015716c 0x1000e8000 + 455020
11  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010014e7fc 0x1000e8000 + 419836
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875729e0 0x187571000 + 6624
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875729a0 0x187571000 + 6560
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875775e8 0x187571000 + 26088
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001886690c8 0x18858e000 + 897224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188666ce4 0x18858e000 + 888036
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188596da4 0x18858e000 + 36260
18  GraphicsServices                0x000000018a001074 0x189ff5000 + 49268
19  UIKit                           0x000000018e84ac9c 0x18e7d6000 + 478364
20  FerretotalApp                   0x00000001000eefe4 0x1000e8000 + 28644
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001875a559c 0x1875a1000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777aca8 0x18777a000 + 3240

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.AsyncLocalStorageQueue
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001876b5014 0x187696000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777f264 0x18777a000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001876299c4 0x1875c8000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001870f51b0 0x1870f4000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018710ec04 0x1870f4000 + 109572
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018711c820 0x187114000 + 34848
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018710b5d4 0x1870f4000 + 95700
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018710aef8 0x1870f4000 + 93944
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018711c66c 0x187114000 + 34412
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001886baf28 0x18858e000 + 1232680
10  FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100103218 0x1000e8000 + 111128
11  FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100126cbc 0x1000e8000 + 257212
12  FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100126524 0x1000e8000 + 255268
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875729e0 0x187571000 + 6624
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875729a0 0x187571000 + 6560
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000187580ad4 0x187571000 + 64212
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875762cc 0x187571000 + 21196
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000187580fa8 0x187571000 + 65448
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000187582a50 0x187571000 + 72272
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001875827d0 0x187571000 + 71632
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777b100 0x18777a000 + 4352
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acac 0x18777a000 + 3244

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777aca8 0x18777a000 + 3240

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001876b5a88 0x187696000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777b1a4 0x18777a000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acac 0x18777a000 + 3244

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187697224 0x187696000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018769709c 0x187696000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188668e90 0x18858e000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188666ae4 0x18858e000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188596da4 0x18858e000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x00000001890b1db4 0x1890a5000 + 52660
6   Foundation                      0x00000001890d2b84 0x1890a5000 + 187268
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f1d4830 0x18e7d6000 + 10479664
8   Foundation                      0x00000001891af318 0x1890a5000 + 1090328
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d68c 0x18777a000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d59c 0x18777a000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acb4 0x18777a000 + 3252

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001876b5a88 0x187696000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777b1a4 0x18777a000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acac 0x18777a000 + 3244

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001876b5a88 0x187696000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777afd0 0x18777a000 + 4048
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acac 0x18777a000 + 3244

Thread 8 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 8:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd55160 0x18c58a000 + 8171872
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
12  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
14  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
15  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
16  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
17  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
18  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
19  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
22  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
23  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
25  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
26  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
27  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
28  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
29  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
30  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
31  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
32  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
33  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
34  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
35  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
36  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
37  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
38  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
39  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
40  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
41  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
42  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
43  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
44  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
45  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
46  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
47  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
48  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
49  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
50  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
51  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
52  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
53  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd50cc8 0x18c58a000 + 8154312
54  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cc3a710 0x18c58a000 + 7014160
55  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c5c7610 0x18c58a000 + 251408
56  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cc6ea4c 0x18c58a000 + 7227980
57  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd57f9c 0x18c58a000 + 8183708
58  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
59  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
60  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
61  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
62  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
63  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
64  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
65  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
66  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
67  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
68  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
69  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
70  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
71  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
72  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
73  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd575d0 0x18c58a000 + 8181200
74  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd5756c 0x18c58a000 + 8181100
75  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd50cc8 0x18c58a000 + 8154312
76  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cc3a710 0x18c58a000 + 7014160
77  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c5c7610 0x18c58a000 + 251408
78  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cc6ea4c 0x18c58a000 + 7227980
79  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd50e10 0x18c58a000 + 8154640
80  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c5c7654 0x18c58a000 + 251476
81  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c8d373c 0x18c58a000 + 3446588
82  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c5c7384 0x18c58a000 + 250756
83  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011f620 0x1000e8000 + 226848
84  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011fe40 0x1000e8000 + 228928
85  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011f1dc 0x1000e8000 + 225756
86  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011eda4 0x1000e8000 + 224676
87  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011eec0 0x1000e8000 + 224960
88  FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100125924 0x1000e8000 + 252196
89  FerretotalApp                   0x0000000100124ce0 0x1000e8000 + 249056
90  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011fe40 0x1000e8000 + 228928
91  Foundation                      0x00000001891af50c 0x1890a5000 + 1090828
92  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018866942c 0x18858e000 + 898092
93  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188668d9c 0x18858e000 + 896412
94  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001886669a8 0x18858e000 + 887208
95  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188596da4 0x18858e000 + 36260
96  FerretotalApp                   0x000000010011ce54 0x1000e8000 + 216660
97  Foundation                      0x00000001891af318 0x1890a5000 + 1090328
98  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d68c 0x18777a000 + 13964
99  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d59c 0x18777a000 + 13724
100 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acb4 0x18777a000 + 3252

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001876b5314 0x187696000 + 127764
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001875d48b0 0x1875c8000 + 51376
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001870e53c4 0x18709e000 + 291780
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf43d2c 0x18c58a000 + 10198316
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf42d6c 0x18c58a000 + 10194284
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf42ba8 0x18c58a000 + 10193832
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf42a50 0x18c58a000 + 10193488
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf43e30 0x18c58a000 + 10198576
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf43d5c 0x18c58a000 + 10198364
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cf4400c 0x18c58a000 + 10199052
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d68c 0x18777a000 + 13964
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d59c 0x18777a000 + 13724
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acb4 0x18777a000 + 3252

Thread 10 name:  WebThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187697224 0x187696000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018769709c 0x187696000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188668e90 0x18858e000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188666ae4 0x18858e000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188596da4 0x18858e000 + 36260
5   WebCore                         0x000000018d261d3c 0x18d21f000 + 273724
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d68c 0x18777a000 + 13964
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d59c 0x18777a000 + 13724
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acb4 0x18777a000 + 3252

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000187697224 0x187696000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018769709c 0x187696000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188668e90 0x18858e000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188666ae4 0x18858e000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188596da4 0x18858e000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000188da3df4 0x188cc2000 + 925172
6   Foundation                      0x00000001891af318 0x1890a5000 + 1090328
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d68c 0x18777a000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777d59c 0x18777a000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018777acb4 0x18777a000 + 3252

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700f0937
    x4: 0x000000018710fb07   x5: 0x000000016e0f1550   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x0000000000000010  x13: 0x0000000188905c0e  x14: 0x0000050000000500  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000016e0f3000  x21: 0x000000016e0f1550  x22: 0x0000000174010810  x23: 0x000000017022e5c0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001740bc5c0  x26: 0x00000001700562f0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0xb000000000000055   fp: 0x000000016e0f14b0   lr: 0x000000018777f264
    sp: 0x000000016e0f1490   pc: 0x00000001876b5014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1000e8000 - 0x1001fbfff FerretotalApp arm64  <840b485c24ee300985053f2079d392c9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4235FE89-BB4B-4025-8EBF-F74C27F0A94F/FerretotalApp.app/FerretotalApp
0x100360000 - 0x100393fff dyld arm64  <93b6f8d0b0c03d8695fbd178c57cb071> /usr/lib/dyld
0x18709c000 - 0x18709dfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <ac92dd7e5a81380bba05c91be3a473ec> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x18709e000 - 0x1870f3fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <da0f6a86db853140b2d79e3b36f28795> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1870f4000 - 0x187110fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <5dc5ba28cfa43f838099049d17ba9ec6> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x187114000 - 0x1874f1fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <85f3b59b96243690b138ce96e663bf4b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1874f2000 - 0x1874f6fff libcache.dylib arm64  <ad6aea8120b33622bc51c6b39587c773> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1874f7000 - 0x187502fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <468e03d6648137679caa585f8bc8e8e8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib

EOF
```

Comment: Did you solve this crash?

Comment: @KML yes sir, it was something related to one of my functions, I was putting boolean instead of string

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already fixed the question. I am writing my approach for the someone who has similar situation.

1. You have to read crash report very carefully.

In the crash report in your question, there are many threads and which one is crashed. In this case `com.facebook.react.AsyncLocalStorageQueue` was the starting point to solve this problem. You may check the code using AsyncStorage.

2. React Native is running in JavaScriptCore.

In the threads which are containing JavasScriptCore, there could be clues which codes were running at the crash moment. In thread 8 in your crash report, there is pretty depth JavaScriptCore call stack. But this call stack is not symbolicated yet. If you keep the archives in your mac, then you can drag your crash report into the Xcode's crash log view. You can follow the Apple's tech notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

After symbolicating, you can presume what's happening in your RN app at crash time.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've changed my answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Probability is because you didn't test your app in release mode. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/18038359/2407880

Comment: thanks, that's ok but I don't have this crash, not even in release mode.