# Upload a new version of ios app to app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store, release

I am new to iOS development. I have updated my application on new system and want to release the new version to App Store. I have gone through the steps to create a new build and upload the application for the first time on app store. However, I am not able to find a way to publish the new version of my application on the app store.

My queries are as follows:
 1. What things I will need ready beforehand?(other than the updated source code)
 2. Do I need to generate/ reuse(If yes where can I get it?) any certificate or keystore(the one we use while signing the Android App)?

I had gone through the following link :https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/

Comment: What do you mean you've upload the application on app store? Is it in iTunes Connect? If so, then go to iTunes Connect and follow the instructions there.

Comment: "However, I am not able to find a way to publish the new version of my application on the app store" Why not? What problem are you actually having?

Comment: @acvm App is already released by someone else. I want to publish an updated version to the app store.

Comment: @matt I dont know how can I do it and what all things I will need

Comment: But why don't you know? It's no secret. It's not our job to read the documentation for you (or to you). If you're actually having a stumbling block, tell us what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about tutorials and follow the official [**App Submission Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Where can I find the steps to generate the release build in xcode?

Comment: Here is a post that explains the steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706548/how-do-i-create-a-release-build-in-xcode

Answer (score 4):

If the project is all set up properly, then simply make sure your Schemes in Xcode are all properly set to "release".

Then archive your app in Xcode through `Product -> Archive` on the top bar

Once that finishes, it should automatically open the Xcode Organizer window (if not, open it through `Window -> Organizer`)

In the Archives tab, select your latest archive and click `Upload to App Store...` and that'll perform some sanity checks and upload it to iTunes Connect.

Once that happens, follow the instructions on that App Submission Guide above.

Comment: It shows me an error saying  *Name Of The Organization* `has one iOS Distribution certificate but its private key is not installed.Contact the creator of this certificate to get a copy of the private key.`
Am I missing something?

Comment: Go here:
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production

If you have a valid distribution profile, then find someone with it and you'll need to install it on your keychain. Otherwise, you can try to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

The certificate for you app is generated based on the unique bundle identifier, so you don't have to worry about getting a certificate.

As for releasing an app to the AppStore, you would need an Apple ID and iTunes Connect. Once your app is on the AppStore, you can then update it whenever and however you like using iTunes Connect. More on that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

Build and test your app to the last line of its code, make sure the application is working as intended to work without crashing or any memory leaks. Then create a distribution certificate using your bundle identifier of your app. Use developer account credentials to login [itunesconnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and follow the instructions.
Once done with that, Create an app in itunes connect with the bundle identifier used for your app on your developer account, fill in all the information required in the app information section. now jump onto Xcode, and make sure you have all assets in place in size required by Apple. Select the distribution provisioning profile and then archive your application, once archived your app can be uploaded with organizer itself or application loader. Now go on itunesconnect and wait for your build that you uploaded to complete processing.

- Fill all the app information and pricing details.
- Upload screenshots of your application.
- Provide demo account credentials if your application requires a login.
- Provide all other bits of information.
- Submit your app for review.

You can also refer [Submitting Your App to the Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) and this latest [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812)