# Which file or directory do I point to for the Application Upload step for the Apple App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have read several sites and they all say to upload the app, but I don't know what the exact file to point to is.  Anybody out there know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a really helpful question which I didn't find.  It is [How can I build for release/distribution on the Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287213/how-can-i-build-for-release-distribution-on-the-xcode-4)

In the answers was one by benvolioT which points to a webpage.  This webpage is just the answer for this question.  It is worth bookmarking.